# How can I float right the User icon?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me on this project, I want to float right or display on the right side the User icon. I'm using a primary bootstrap from getbootstrap.com

[image]

```
    [![<ul class="nav nav-t][1]][1]abs">
  [<li role="presentation"><a href="index][1].php">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="trucks.php">Trucks</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="suppliers.php">Suppliers</a></li>
  <li role="presenation"><a href="accountspayables.php">Uploaded Files</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="maintenance.php">Maintenance</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you even looked at the [**Bootstrap Documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to close your `<span>` with `</span>`

Use `pull-right`, in case you wonder what's inside this bootstrap class, here it is:

```
// Classes
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="index][1].php">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="trucks.php">Trucks</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="suppliers.php">Suppliers</a></li>
  <li role="presenation"><a href="accountspayables.php">Uploaded Files</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="maintenance.php">Maintenance</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="pull-right"><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ArjayLegaspi cool, If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!